# slideToggle on page load

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code which toggles a container on click

```
// START JQUERY TOGGLE SUBMENUS
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".toggle_container").hide();
  jQuery("li.trigger a").click(function() {
    jQuery(".toggle_container").hide();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

how can i open a specific item on page load?

Comment: Use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) on the `.trigger a` element to fire a click event perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the end of your `(document).ready`:

```
jQuery("li.trigger a").eq(0).click();
```

This will click the first `li.trigger a`.  Change the value in `.eq()` to be whichever item you want opened on page load, starting from 0.